# How do I pass a NSDate using storyboard properly?

Tags: ios5, set, xcode4.2

I want to pass a NSDate from **PickDateController** to **DetailViewController**
so on **PickDateController** I have an IBAction as follows:

```
-(IBAction)doneDate:(id)sender{

NSLog(@"Date Here DPC = %@", [datePicker.date description]); //This shows fine
dateLabel.text = [datePicker.date description]; //This also shows.

DetailViewController *controller = [[[DetailViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

NSDate *dateSel = datePicker.date;
[controller setDateSelected:dateSel]; //This DOES NOT go to DetailViewController
controller.dateSelected = dateSel; //This doesn't work either

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

For a dummy like me what am I missing ?
How should I write the -(void)setDateSelected{} on DetailViewController ? Or is it not the issue ?

Comment: Is `DetailViewController` part of the storyboard? Are there any segues  between these controllers? If you use `alloc/init`, you wont get the controller instantiated by the storyboard. If you have a segue between those, you don't nee dto create a new controller but rather implement `prepareForSegue` in your view controller.

Comment: Yes Both controllers are part of the storyboard. There is a segue from DetailViewController to PickDateController so I figure I could just popViewController to "dismiss" the PickDateController but the variable doesn't get passed to DetailViewController. Do I have to create another segue going BACK to DetailViewController after I pick the date ?

Comment: No, you need to create a sort of `PickDateControllerDelegate` and a `delegate` property on your `PickDateController`. You then can set the delegate to your calling `DetailViewController`, in the `prepareForSegue` method of your `DetailViewController`. You now can access it via `self.delegate` from within your `PickDateController`. Take a look at http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2 for a good example. Basically the rule is: segues only go "in", never "back".

Comment: @TriPhoenix ..I got: "@synthesize ok 'weak' property is only allowed in ARC or GC mode" ? Is there a way to change it to an understandable "@property" method for it still ? Thanks for your help so far...

Comment: You can use an `assign` property instead of `weak` if you're not using ARC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that there are existing segues between the controllers and `DetailViewController` did a segue to `PickDateController`:

If you use `alloc/init`, you wont get the controller instantiated by the storyboard. If you have a segue between those, you don't need to create a new controller but rather implement `prepareForSegue` in your view controller to create a "back channel" (in order to pass the information back you cannot create a new segue back (they only go "in", never "back"): 
You need to create a sort of `PickDateControllerDelegate` and a delegate property on your `PickDateController`. You then can set the `delegate` to your calling `DetailViewController`, in the `prepareForSegue` method of your `DetailViewController`.

You now can access it via `self.delegate` from within your `PickDateController` and thus report any information back before being dismissed / poped form the navigation stack. The `delegate` can and should also be used to inform the calling controller that it may dismiss the `PickDateController` (instead of dismissing itself).

[Beginning Storyboards, part 2](http://raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2) is a good reference on doing this (you can use `assign` and `retain` properties for `weak` and `strong` if you're not using ARC yet.